# Class as a type for properties of another class in flow?

Tags: javascript, class, properties, flowtype

I have a class called `Foo` and in the class `Bar` I want to set a property `Kan` as the type `Foo`, in flow, something like this:

```
// @flow
class Foo {
  kan: Bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind just import the class.

```
// @flow

import Bar from './Bar';

class Foo {
  kan: Bar
}
```